# HTML Canvas and CSS

Tags: css, canvas

I am wondering if CSS can be used to style something that in being rendered by a canvas?

For example, flot uses canvas to draw the charts however highcharts uses SVG.  Since SVG seems basically like a XML document, I can see that it would be very easy to style things highcharts creates with CSS.  Since creating a canvas does not create any extra markup, I would think it is not possible to customize the style through CSS (though I am asking this question since I am not very familiar with canvas).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but I think that using CSS in canvas directly is not possible. But you can try to read style from other HTML element (that uses CSS) and map it to canvas using its JS API. Here is an example how it could be done:
http://tjholowaychuk.com/post/6339741902/styling-canvas-drawings-with-css

But as I mentioned I'm not an expert and maybe someone found easiest solution.